# Looking for an English translation of "On Analytical Methods In Probability Theory" by Kolmogorov

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

I am looking for an English translation of Kolmogoroff, A.
*Über die analytischen Methoden in der Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung.* (German)
**Math. Ann.** 104 (1931), no. 1, 415–458. The title in English is "On Analytical Methods In Probability Theory". I can only find Russian and German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that an English translation can be found in Kolmogorov's Selected Works (vol 2) pp. 62–108, 1992, Kluwer.